# Can I become an Ubuntu Member by contributing on Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-membership

The [Ubuntu Membership Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Membership) states:

> Contributions are valued and recognized whether you contribute to
>   artwork, any of the LoCoTeams, documentation, providing support on the
>   forums, the answers tracker, IRC support, bug triage, translation,
>   development and packaging, marketing and advocacy, contributing to the
>   wiki, or anything else.

This defines what contributions will be considered valuable when applying for Ubuntu membership. What I want to know is, does my involvement on **Ask Ubuntu** fall under the stipulation "...or anything else"?

I'd imagine they don't *literally* mean anything else, just things considered to fit the scope of contributing to Ubuntu. So is my help here valuable in contributing? Has anyone ever obtained membership by using their **Ask Ubuntu** contributions as their argument toward membership?

Comment: I lost count of the number of people who became Ubuntu member via Ask Ubuntu. :-)

Comment: @jokerdino Awesome! I've been an Ubuntu user for 6 years and wanted a way to give back. It's great that I stand a chance at also becoming an official member.

Comment: @jokerdino I think a link should mention to describe procedure to apply via Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Plenty of people on the site (including all the moderators) have cited their involvement here as a sustained contribution to Ubuntu as a means to membership, so, yes!

Comment: Should one note that *just* Ask Ubuntu is not enough in most cases?